# Are there any examples for how to draw a line chart in Core Plot on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, core-plot

Is there some sample code or a tutorial out there about how to draw a line chart using the Core Plot framework?  I can't find anything using Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have downloaded the [framework](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/), go to the `examples` directory within your checked-out version.  There are several examples there, including CPTestApp-iPhone (which demonstrates line, bar, and pie charts), CPTestApp-iPad (same, but for the iPad), StockPlot (which downloads stock charts and plots the line graphs for them), and AAPLot (which grabs Apple's stock price and plots it using an open-high-low-close chart).

These examples are updated as the API changes, so they can be considered reliable sources to work from.

Answer (score 6):

I've created a Core Plot "Hello World" with an x^2 graph here: http://recycled-parts.blogspot.com/2011/08/coreplot-hello-world.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: This post is no longer available publicly @mondousage.