# Line graphs on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cgcontext, linegraph

Anyone know how to create line graphs on iOS without using Core-Plot but using inbuilt frameworks? Desperately searching for an answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Some of the charting libraries for iPhone/iPad that I found were:

http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/

http://sebkade.wordpress.com/2010/05/06/basic-graph-class-for-iphone/

http://www.rgraph.net/

You can use whatever you feel convenient with.

I would prefer using [Core Plot Library](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) though

Hope this helps you.

**EDIT**:

You can refer to this link to integrate the graph library core plot into your app.

http://tech.pro/tutorial/939/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application

And once your core plot repository is downloaded,you can go to the folder suggested by Brad Larson (in the below link) to get a tutorial for line chart.

[Are there any examples for how to draw a line chart in Core Plot on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934357/are-there-any-examples-for-how-to-draw-a-line-chart-in-core-plot-on-the-iphone/2934964#2934964)

Also you can refer it here:

http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/browse/#hg/examples

Comment: Did this answer help you? Did you refer to any other libraries?

Comment: Sorry! My company had a network issue. About the answer, some of the links don't work. And I did mention in my question that I didn't endorse core-plot (I was asked not to by my senior lead) and I wanted something with the inbuilt frameworks. In fact, if I were to be honest, none of the links were helpful. But seriously, thanks for the effort! :)

I am currently scrutinizing the CoreGraphics methods.

Comment: Actually can you ask your senior what is wrong with the core-plot?

Comment: Will do. :) Do you have any sample code that uses core-plot to plot line graphs? I am going crazy with this thing!

Comment: @Joel Joseph: Downlaod the core plot repository. There under the repository itself it has multiple examples which shows each and every kind of charts it supports. Tutorial for line graph is included in that repository itself.

Comment: @Joel Joseph: You can refer to **EDIT** section of my answer for directions about the line chart example and integration of core-plot in iphone app.

Comment: +1 for Core-plot, which is a fabulous library.

Comment: @Kheldar: Thanks a lot. Yeah I agree core plot is the most fabulous carting library available atleast for iOS.

Comment: @Parth I believe he asked "without using Core-Plot but using inbuilt frameworks?"

Comment: Just recently made my project open check it out: https://github.com/jsetting32/JSGraphKit

Answer (score 5):

Apple have some sample code for drawing graphic in Quartz here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AccelerometerGraph/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: This code doesn't plot any graph for me on the simulator. :S Any idea what could be the reason? I use iOS SDK 4.3 version. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: this code uses accelerometer reading which won't be available in simulator

Comment: ...you should have access to a device when developing. There's no point just testing your apps on the simulator alone, it doesn't reflect what actually happens on the real device.

Answer (score 3):

As well as CorePlot, there are several commercial tools for iOS charting:

- [ShinobiControls](http://www.shinobicontrols.com)
- [www.threedgraphics.com](http://www.shinobicontrols.com/)
- [iPhone Charting Library for iPhone Objective-C](http://www.keepedge.com/products/iphone_charting/)

*As a **full disclosure**, I work for Scott Logic which is the parent company for ShinobiControls.*

Comment: Since your profile says you work closely with the ninjas who develop ShinobiControls, this recommendation isn't entirely frank.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler sorry, I see your point. I have added a full disclosure, which is I believe acceptable form for this sort of thing on StackOverflow.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have also changed the answer to include all the commercial charting libraries I am aware of that are not detailed in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [CoreAnimation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html), [CoreGraphics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreGraphics/Reference/CoreGraphics_Framework/_index.html), [Quartz](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html) frameworks.

Comment: Hmmm..What do I say, I was hoping for a more concrete answer. I am quite new to this development field. I did have an idea I had to use CoreGraphics and Quartz frameworks. Anyways, thanks for the help! Appreciated. :)